# React and MySQL. got Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I connected React with MySQL database and it works well when I take inputs and pass them in the database. But when I try to print all the data in the MySQL database, I can only successfully print the columns age and email, but not name and course. More specifically, the name and course are simply just not showing, yet the other two columns are working with no problem. I can see all the correct information from the database in the console, but they are not shown properly on the page. The column age is of type int/number, name, course, and email are of type varchar.
In the console, I got the warning in the question summary. Below is my code in App.js. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import './App.css';
import {useState} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [newCourse, setNewCourse] = useState("");
  const [stuList, setStuList] = useState([]);

  const getStudents = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/students").then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setStuList(response.data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="showStudents">
        <button onClick={getStudents}>Show Students</button>

        {stuList.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <div className="students">
              <div>
                <h3>Name: {val.name}</h3>
                <h3>Age: {val.age}</h3>
                <h3>Email: {val.email}</h3>
                <h3>Course: {val.course}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unique id been sent out in the API you can add `<div className="students" key={val.id}>` or else you can use the index of the array. The index of an array comes with a drawback. please refer this: [https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:~:text=We%20don't%20recommend%20using,an%20index%20as%20a%20key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:%7E:text=We%20don%27t%20recommend%20using,an%20index%20as%20a%20key).

To print the data, you need to use templateliteral. please refer the answer below

```
 useEffect(()=> {
     getStudents()
 }, [])


 return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="showStudents">
        <button onClick={getStudents}>Show Students</button>

        {stuList.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <div className="students" key={key}>
              <div>
                <h3>{`Name: ${val.name}`}</h3>
                <h3>{`Age: ${val.age}`}</h3>
                <h3>{`Email: ${val.email}`}</h3>
                <h3>{`Course: ${val.course}`}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! But after I changed everything the name and course of every student object become "undefined" instead of not showing anything.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct value ? can you please do a console log of stuList.

Comment: Oh you're right. If I console log stuList it returns an empty array. But why is it not passing the data? I get the correct data if i do console log(response)

Comment: You need to call the function getStudents inside the useEffect hook. I have updated the answer

Comment: would be nice if you could accept the answer as the correct one. It would help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `key` attribute to the parent of the elements you are returning in the map method. The values need to be unique to React can identify what changes to apply and where.

```js
import './App.css';
import {useState} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [newCourse, setNewCourse] = useState("");
  const [stuList, setStuList] = useState([]);

  const getStudents = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/students").then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setStuList(response.data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="showStudents">
        <button onClick={getStudents}>Show Students</button>

        {stuList.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <div key={key} className="students">
              <div>
                <h3>Name: {val.name}</h3>
                <h3>Age: {val.age}</h3>
                <h3>Email: {val.email}</h3>
                <h3>Course: {val.course}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I added key={key} but it didn't change. How does React get the primary key of the table in MySQL? Should I add another function to pass the primary key to React?

Comment: @jdyeux This has nothing to do with MySQL or any primary keys, the key={key} is a way for React to compare the two different trees(virtual DOM tree & real one) and decide what to update if a change has happened and that's why it gives you warnings if forgot to include in list items.